# Emacs: Can't activate input method

Tags: emacs

My default input method has always been configured this way:

(setq default-input-method "russian-computer")

Something broke, and all I get is this message (on top of the execution stack, if I'm interpreting it right) as soon as I press C-\:

activate-input-method: Can't activate input method `russian-computer'

It used to work without a hitch. There has been no intervention that I'm aware of; I'd like to get some clues.

Comment: Take a look at the variable input-method-alist by typing `C-h v input-method-alist` - do you see an entry for "russian-computer" in the returned list?

Comment: input-method-alist's value is nil

Comment: Could you also please check the variable `load-path` and look for an entry that contains a directory called "leim".

Comment: (... "/usr/share/emacs/23.1/leim") The leim directory is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs loads the input-methods it knows from a directory called "leim" (Library of Emacs Input Methods). The location of the code to load should be something like

```
/usr/share/emacs/<version>/leim/leim-list.el
```

(For the exact location, search for an entry containing the word "leim" in your `load-path` variable by typing <kbd>C-h v load-path</kbd>.)

If you inspect that file, you should see an entry

```lisp
(register-input-method
 "russian-computer" "Russian" 'quail-use-package
 "RU" "ЙЦУКЕН Russian computer layout"
 "quail/cyrillic")
```

which refers to a subdirectory of the "leim" directory called "quail".

Make sure that both the file `leim-list.el` and the sub-directory `quail` exist on your system. The quail directory is distributed separately from the Emacs source code, so if you installed from source, make sure you included the leim-list package. See here (scroll to bottom):

http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/

If the leim directory is empty, you might consider re-installing emacs.